# Hiding axis text in matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a figure without tickmarks or numbers on either of the axes (I use axes in the traditional sense, not the matplotlib nomenclature!). An issue I have come across is where matplotlib adjusts the x(y)ticklabels by subtracting a value N, then adds N at the end of the axis.

This may be vague, but the following simplified example highlights the issue, with '6.18' being the offending value of N:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
prefix = 6.18

rx = [prefix+(0.001*random.random()) for i in arange(100)]
ry = [prefix+(0.001*random.random()) for i in arange(100)]
plt.plot(rx,ry,'ko')

frame1 = plt.gca()
for xlabel_i in frame1.axes.get_xticklabels():
    xlabel_i.set_visible(False)
    xlabel_i.set_fontsize(0.0)
for xlabel_i in frame1.axes.get_yticklabels():
    xlabel_i.set_fontsize(0.0)
    xlabel_i.set_visible(False)
for tick in frame1.axes.get_xticklines():
    tick.set_visible(False)
for tick in frame1.axes.get_yticklines():
    tick.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

The three things I would like to know are:

1. How to turn off this behaviour in the first place (although in most cases it is useful, it is not always!) I have looked through `matplotlib.axis.XAxis` and cannot find anything appropriate
2. How can I make N disappear (i.e. `X.set_visible(False)`)
3. Is there a better way to do the above anyway? My final plot would be 4x4 subplots in a figure, if that is relevant.

Comment: I have a little doubt if any of the answers here actually answer the question. To me it looks like the question asks how to [get rid of the offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171064/matplotlib-remove-axis-label-offset-by-default). Yet all the answers show various ways how to get rid of *all* the ticklabels. If the question has been superseeded by the answers, maybe one should edit the question to ask for what the answers provide solutions for?

Answer (score 668, accepted):

Instead of hiding each element, you can hide the whole axis:

```
frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Or, you can set the ticks to an empty list:

```
frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

In this second option, you can still use `plt.xlabel()` and `plt.ylabel()` to add labels to the axes.

Answer (score 302):

If you want to hide just the axis text keeping the grid lines:

```
frame1 = plt.gca()
frame1.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
frame1.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
```

Doing `set_visible(False)` or `set_ticks([])` will also hide the grid lines.

Answer (score 225):

If you are like me and don't always retrieve the axes, `ax`, when plotting the figure, then a simple solution would be to do

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: I just do `plt.axis('off')` for a one-stop shop.

Comment: This also removes gridlines (if any).

Answer (score 155):

I've colour coded this figure to ease the process.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

[image]

You can have full control over the figure using these commands, to complete the answer I've add also the control over the spines:

```
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# X AXIS -BORDER
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
# BLUE
ax.set_xticklabels([])
# RED
ax.set_xticks([])
# RED AND BLUE TOGETHER
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

# Y AXIS -BORDER
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# YELLOW
ax.set_yticklabels([])
# GREEN
ax.set_yticks([])
# YELLOW AND GREEN TOGHETHER
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 102):

I was not actually able to render an image without borders or axis data based on any of the code snippets here (even the one accepted at the answer). After digging through some API documentation, I landed on this code to render my image

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, top=False, right=False, bottom=False, labelleft=False, labeltop=False, labelright=False, labelbottom=False)
plt.savefig('foo.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

I used the `tick_params` call to basically shut down any extra information that might be rendered and I have a perfect graph in my output file.

Answer (score 68):

Somewhat of an old thread but, this seems to be a faster method using the latest version of matplotlib:

set the major formatter for the x-axis

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
```

Comment: This method also keeps ticks and grids intact

Answer (score 19):

One trick could be setting the color of tick labels as white to hide it!

```
plt.xticks(color='w')
plt.yticks(color='w')
```

or to be more generalized (@Armin Okić), you can set it as `"None"`.

Answer (score 17):

When using the object oriented API, the `Axes` object has two useful methods for removing the axis text, [`set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) and [`set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks).

Say you create a plot using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

If you simply want to remove the tick labels, you could use

```
ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

or to remove the ticks completely, you could use

```
ax.set_xticks([])
```

These methods are useful for specifying exactly where you want the ticks and how you want them labeled.  Passing an empty list results in no ticks, or no labels, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply set `xlabel` to `None`, straight in your axis. Below an working example using seaborn

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax.set(xlabel=None)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in case you have subplots

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 8))

ax[0].set_yticklabels([]) # x-axis
ax[0].set_xticklabels([]) # y-axis
```

Comment: Axis comments are reversed, but otherwise it works.

Answer (score 1):

How to let the tick labels stay but the *axis* label go away:

`axs.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following line of code:

```
plt.axis("off")
```

Should solve the issue for you.