# How to show separate boxplots for all columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

When I try to show boxplots for all columns I used this command:

```
df_num.boxplot(rot=90)
```

[image]

But as you can see the boxes are so tiny as their ranges are different and should not be sharing the same y-axis. Can I do something like below but in boxplots? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way (example including just 2 of the columns but you can obviously add more):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6), ncols=2)
df_num["backers_count"].plot.box(ax=ax[0])
df_num["converted_pledged_amount"].plot.box(ax=ax[1]);
```

...or with Seaborn:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6), ncols=2)
sns.boxplot(data=df_num, y="backers_count", ax=ax[0])
sns.boxplot(data=df_num, y="converted_pledged_amount", ax=ax[1]);
```

If you want to display them in a grid of, say 3 rows and 3 columns then you can change the `ncols=2` bit to `nrows=3, ncols=3`, and then instead of `ax=ax[0]`, `ax=ax[1]` etc you would write `ax=ax[0,0]`, `ax=ax[0,1]` etc

Comment: Got it! Thank you! But is there anyway that only the right amount of boxes are shown? Cause I have 11 graphs and by using `nrows=4, ncols=3` there will be an empty plot at the end. Thanks!

Comment: See this post for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035446/how-can-i-make-a-blank-subplot-in-matplotlib