# How to remove values on x,y axis on plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to remove the x/y axis numbers(values) from a plot?
I still want to keep the frame and grid in the plot though.
/Jonas

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots

Comment: Yes thanks, however is there a way to still have a grid in the plot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

depending on how you have created the plot... the simplest way would be to set the xaxis tick to an empty list

```
from matplotlib import pylab

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,4,6,8,10]

pylab.plot(x,y)
frame = pylab.gca()

frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

pylab.show()
```

Comment: Yes thanks, however is there a way to still have a grid in the plot?

Comment: set_ticklabels([]) instead of set_ticks([])

Comment: It would be better to use `NullLocator` and `NullForamatter`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ax[i].set_axis_off()` if you are using subplots.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_off.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).