# How to hide ticks label in python but keep the ticks in place?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, label

I want to hide my ticks label on a plot I created, but keep this tick itself (the little marks on the axis). When I try to use what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots), for example, the entire tick is removed, and not just the labels. How can I remove only the labels then?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the tick labels not to be an empty array, but to be a list of empty strings. In the example below, I've replaced the xtick labels with empty strings, leaving the y axis untouched. From here you can selectively keep certain labels if you wished.

```
import pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]

empty_string_labels = ['']*len(labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(empty_string_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This code is adapted from [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/249341).

Comment: you can do `ax.set_yticklabels([])` without having to initialise a list of empty strings.

Answer (score 135):

Here is a slightly simpler answer, using [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)    

plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting output in Matplotlib 3

[image]

As commented by @chris, one can similarly hide the labels on any of the other axes using `labeltop`, `labelleft`, `labelright`, in the above example, instead of `labelbottom`.

Comment: note for those arriving here to find out how to hide labels on other axes, `ax.tick_params` accepts the following keyword args: `labelbottom`, `labeltop`, `labelleft`, `labelright`

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, IMO.

Comment: Also prefer this method, as the ax.set_xticklabels([]) method also disables the get_major_formatter().get_offset()

Answer (score 7):

I didn't find divenex's answer to work for me. This answer creates ticks without triggering any automatic labeling, hence no requirement to use "labelbottom= False":

if the bottom and left ticks already exist:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

ax.tick_params(right= True,top= True)
```

if no ticks already exist:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

ax.tick_params(right= True,top= True,left= True, bottom= True)
```

Comment: This answer does not hide the labels. It creates the ticks, leaving the labels unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: the most neat answer for this!