# How do I hide x-axis label in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I used the following command to plot my data:

```
df.plot(x='_time', y='IdCount', kind='bar')
```

And got this chart:

[image: khrkf]

In order to remove the black characters below the graph I would like to hide the label for the x-axis. How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936658/how-to-hide-ticks-label-in-python-but-keep-the-ticks-in-place

Comment: While removing the x-ticks will make it look cleaner, it could make sense to plot it with regural line plot, possibly with filled color under the curve. See, for example [this figure](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/_images/recipes-4.png) at [matplotlib recipes](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/users/recipes.html#fill-between-and-alpha)

Comment: But how do I apply this to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: `ax = df.plot(x='_time', y='IdCount', kind='bar')`... then apply the solution in the linked duplicate to `ax`.