# Hide tick label values but keep axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this image:

```
plt.plot(sim_1['t'],sim_1['V'],'k')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to hide the numbers; if I use:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

...I get this image:

[image]

It also hide the labels, `V` and `t`. How can I keep the labels while hiding the values?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

If you use the matplotlib [object-oriented approach](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles), this is a simple task using [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) and [`ax.set_yticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html). Here we can just set them to an empty list to remove any labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Figure and Axes instances
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Make your plot, set your axes labels
ax.plot(sim_1['t'],sim_1['V'],'k')
ax.set_ylabel('V')
ax.set_xlabel('t')

# Turn off tick labels
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

If you also want to remove the tick marks as well as the labels, you can use [`ax.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) and [`ax.set_yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) and set those to an empty list as well:

```
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

Answer (score 126):

Without a `subplots`, you can universally remove the ticks like this:

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 65):

This works great. Just paste this before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 7):

to remove tickmarks entirely use:

```
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xticks([])
```

otherwise `ax.set_yticklabels([])` and `ax.set_xticklabels([])` will keep tickmarks.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this is the best way, but you can certainly replace the tick labels like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x," ")
plt.show()
```

In Python 3.4 this generates a simple line plot with no tick labels on the x-axis.  A simple example is here:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

This related question also has some better suggestions:
[Hiding axis text in matplotlib plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots?rq=1)

I'm new to python.  Your mileage may vary in earlier versions.  Maybe others can help?

Answer (score 4):

`plt.gca().axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This also works.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
```

see this book for nice tips for customizing ticks
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html

Answer (score 2):

With this is enough:

```
plt.xticks(color='w')
```

Comment: Only if you set the background to white. Default background in jupyter/savefig is transparent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQWZB.png