# How to remove axis values in matplotlib 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I remove the axis values in a matplotlib 3d plot? A random plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
a = .6
b = 1.2


zline = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
xline = zline*.6
yline = zline*1.2
ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, 'gray')


zdata = 15 * np.random.random(100)
xdata = zdata*.6 + 2 * np.random.randn(100)
ydata = zdata*1.2 + 1 * np.random.randn(100)
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c='red')


w = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color(w)
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color(w)
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color(w)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I use `ax.set_xticks([])` for all axes I get

[image]

I still want to keep the lines in the plot and only remove the axis values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide tick label values but keep axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039685/hide-tick-label-values-but-keep-axis-labels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the tick labels. Add the following lines before `plt.show()`.

```py
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
```