# Remove text from figure when using dataframe.boxplot(by=...)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using this simplified code to create mutiple boxplots:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

df["index"]=range(1,len(df)+1)
df["CustomColumn"]=0

header=list(df.columns)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(10,  5), sharey=False)
boxplot=df.boxplot(by=CustomColumn, layout=(1,5), ax=axs)
plt.savefig("DataframeBoxplot.png")
plt.show()
```

For some other reason I need to group the boxplots by a `CustomColumn`.
Are there any possibilities to remove the `[CustomColumns]` under the plots as shown in the figure below?

[image: BoxPlots]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding axis text in matplotlib plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am sorry for missing this. I had to iterate over the axes:                                                                                                                                
for axis in axs:
     axis.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)