# How to remove extra X label in below barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

Help me to remove extra X label (funding_round_type) in below barplot. Also help me in displaying values for each bar on it.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

funding_group_plt = funding_group.loc[['seed','venture','private_equity','angel']]

print(funding_group_plt)

funding_group_plt.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,5), color = ['g', 'orange','blue','yellow'],width = 1)
plt.ylabel('Avg. Raised Amount in USD (in Millions)', fontsize=20)
plt.title ('Suited funding type for investment',fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

---

```
funding_round_type
seed               0.738632
venture           11.895456
private_equity    75.575805
angel              0.979917
Name: raised_amount_usd, dtype: float64
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding axis text in matplotlib plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots)

Comment: `funding_group_plt.rename_axis(index=None).plot(...)`?

Comment: It is not working.