# How i can delete xlabel of plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I don't need the xlabels. because of this I wish to delete/leave this. How can I do that?

```
plt.title('Amount of kill per country', pad= 15, fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Kills', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Country', fontsize=14)
plt.show()

[ploting and coding][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4km5J.png
```

Comment: Two good options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176591/42346

Comment: I don't think that stack overflow link answers this question.  This is about the axis labels, not the tick labels.  OTOH, I'm not sure what the question is.  Don't type `plt.xlabel()` and you won't get an xlabel.

Comment: A most simplicty way is change the color of xlabel. Turn the color "white" like background.