# matplotlib: How to turn off figure box without Lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am visualization multi-time series lines and want to show without axis. I have tried multiple solutions from google but could not successful.

Here is the code:

```
f = plt.figure(frameon=False)
f.set_figwidth(4)
f.set_figheight(1)
plt.plot(x, linewidth=1.5)
```

Here is the output of the above code:

[image]

Any idea how to turn off this box from the lines?

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire box (all the 4 borders)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed the code via getting help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots%27) and @Ravindra code.

Here is the final code:

```
 f.set_figwidth(4)
 f.set_figheight(1)
 plt.plot(x, linewidth=1.5)
 for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)
 frame1 = plt.gca()
 frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
 frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
    
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: I have edited your post according to the output of your given code. Please read it.

Comment: yeah, already. It also off the lines

Comment: No, it also hide the lines. And I want to visualize the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not a hundred percent sure what you mean by 'axis', but you can get rid of the frame by setting this:

```
plt.box(False)
```

[image]

So this is how it looks like:

Comment: Already tried this and this off the lines as well.